# Easiest way to go about writing basic data back to a server database

Tags: javascript, php, database

I am totally new to writing back data to a server, so this question may be phrased slightly wrongly.

I am building a website that will have multiple fields for users to input values. I am planning on using JS (probably with Jquery) to pass these values to be stored on some kind of database. I would then like to recall the values and display them back into the site (again using JS).

Ill have to make some calculations based on all the values within the database and would like the end result of these calculations to also be called back onto the website through JS.

Basically i dont even know where to start.. everything i read about this topic seems to be aimed at someone who already knows how to initially set up a database and what kind to use. My scripting is rather on the basic side, so something fairly intuative from the database would be really handy.

Does anyone have any suggestions what sort of database i should set up and how i can begin learning this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at https://www.codecademy.com

It's free and they have easy to follow courses that will teach you all the technologies you'll need to know to build an interactive web application.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out php (server language) and mysql (database). You should install wamp if you are on a windows server, or mamp for mac. Play around with php and then create your database and play with that. In mysql there is a new interface called PDO for database connection and database requests, you might wanna look into that. Google is your friend and read a lot and try stuff, that is how you learn it. you might also wanna consider taking online classes.